# Rolling paper and tissue

Tags: одним-словом

I am studying russian and sometimes in the dictionary i find words that seems too much 'academical'.

I wanted to ask clarification about two words:

- Tissue (the paper to clean to the nose) in russian is:    **бумажный носовой платок** ?
  There is perhaps a short form to refer to it?
- Rolling paper (to roll a cigarette) is: **прокатки бумаги** ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"*Tissue*" is usually translated as "*носовой платок*", regardless of material one is made from.

"*Rolling paper*" can be referred as "*сигаретная бумага*", "*папиросная бумага*" or as "*бумага для самокруток*". If you need to buy paper for rolling machine it is more correct to ask for the last.

Comment: No, "носовой платок" is always "платок" made of fabric, not from the paper.

Comment: In colloquial speech just "платок"/"платочек" is used. If it's made of paper, you can also say "салфетка".

Comment: "Платок" generally is a piece of cloth, usually square or triangular. It can be used as item of clothing like headscarf or shawl. See [link](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Платок) for more meanings. So I think it is better to clarify and use "носовой платок" referring to "tissue".

Comment: Ok, so if i go in a grocery store to but tissue i will ask for бумажный носовой платок  and in a tobacco shop i will ask for сигаретная бумага.

And as kemerover say, in colloquial speech, i can ask my friend to give me one платок, right?

Comment: In appropriate context - of course you can. For example: you have just sniffed badly and asking your friend - _У тебя есть чистый платок?_

Comment: But I've never heard _бумажный носовой платок_ in colloquial speech. _Салфетка_ is usually used referring paper napkin and _влажная салфетка_ stands for _wet wipe_.

Comment: *У тебя есть чистый платок?* - I would never give my платок - just a салфетка in such case. I don't want to carry the платок after it was used in such way.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know how to say "бумажный носовой платок" in one word. Usually these three words are used. Or sometimes there can be "бумажные салфетки" which is actually is the same in that context. Салфетка (napkin) is a paper or cloth used to clean the mouth after eating.

For "прокатка бумаги" there is a "скрутить" (skrutit') word (to curl up). Speaking about hand made cigarette there is a word "самокрутка" (samokrutka). That means a cigarette made by скручивание (skruchivanie) of parer by yourself (сам-)